# Matlab: Improving a tree traversal code

Tags: file, matlab, data-structures, tree

I have the structure that is demonstrated below:

[image: database structure]

I have a `database` folder which contains `brands`. Each `brand` consists of `logo` and `query`.
I want to traverse on all the the files (`file_1` to `file_n`) in all the `database` and perform some operations on them.

I wrote this code:

```
d = dir(database);
isub = [d(:).isdir];
brandsFolders = {d(isub).name}';
brandsFolders(ismember(brandsFolders,{'.','..'})) = [];
[numberOfBrands not_used]=size(brandsFolders); %holds the number of the brands
for i=1:numberOfBrands
    temp=strcat(database,  '\');
    currentBrand=strcat(temp, brandsFolders(i));
    d = dir(currentBrand{1,1});
    isub = [d(:).isdir];
    logoAndQuery = {d(isub).name}';
    logoAndQuery(ismember(logoAndQuery,{'.','..'})) = [];
    logo=strcat(currentBrand, '\', logoAndQuery(1));
    files=dir(logo{1,1});
    [numberOfFiles not_used]=size(files);
    for j=1:numberOfFiles
        if strcmp(files(j).name, '..')~=1 && strcmp(files(j).name, '.')~=1
            %operations on each files(j).name
        end
    end
end
```

The code *works fine*, it traverse on the desired files.
However, the code is little bit ugly and confusing.

**I was wondering if I can do it in another better way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traversing through a set of directories goes pretty much as you are doing. However imo, there are some things you can do easier / I would do differently:

```
brandsFolders = dir(database);
brandsFolders( ~[brandsFolders.isdir] | strcmp({brandsFolders.name},'.') | strcmp({brandsFolders.name},'..')) = [];

for ii=1:numel(brandsFolders)
    logoAndQuery  = dir(fullfile(database,brandsFolders(ii).name));
    logoAndQuery( ~[logoAndQuery.isdir] | strcmp({logoAndQuery.name},'.') | strcmp({logoAndQuery.name},'..')) = [];

    logo = fullfile(databasecurrentBrand,brandsFolders(ii).name), logoAndQuery(1).name);
    files = dir(logo);
    files(strcmp({files.name},'.') | strcmp({files.name},'..'))=[];

    for jj=1:numel(files)
        %operations on each files(j).name
    end
end
```

(This of course only works if you're sure that `logoAndQuery(1)` will always be the 'logo' directory.)
or alternatively use a subfunction for the dir-querying:

```
function dirs = getDirs(strPath)
    dirs = dir(strPath);
    dirnames = {dirs.name};
    dirs ( ~[dirs.isdir] | strcmp(dirnames ,'.') | strcmp(dirnames ,'..')) = [];
end
```

which gives you already some shorter code and gives the following, in which I also assume there are no directories in the 'logo' directories:

```
brandsFolders = getDirs(database);

for ii=1:numel(brandsFolders)
    logoAndQuery  = getDirs(fullfile(database,brandsFolders(ii).name));
    logo = fullfile(databasecurrentBrand,brandsFolders(ii).name), logoAndQuery(1).name);
    files = dir(logo);
    files([files.isdir])=[];

    for jj=1:numel(files)
        %operations on each files(j).name
    end
end
```