# Import multiple tab delimited files into matlab from different subdirectories

Tags: matlab

Sorry I am new to matlab.

What I have: A folder containing about 80 subfolders, labeled Day01, Day02, Day03, etc. Each subfolder has a file called "sample_ids.txt" It is a n x m matrix in a tab delimited format.

What I need: 1 data structure that is an array of matrices, where each matrix is the data from "sample_ids.txt" and it should be in the alphabetical order of Day01, Day02, Day03, etc.

I have no idea how to get from point A to point B. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There were a lot of questions like this on this forum. You should search before posting a new question.

Comment: I did look but I didn't find the right answer.

Comment: @yuk: If you've found duplicates, could you please link them here? That way we can close this question as a dupe, and refer the OP to the previous ones.

Comment: Here is one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546701/matlab-improving-a-tree-traversal-code

Answer (score 0):

You can decompose this problem into two parts: finding the files, and reading them into memory.

Finding the files is pretty easy, and has [already been covered on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621846/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-in-matlab).

For loading them into memory, you want a multidimensional array, which is as simple as creating a regular array and start using more index dimensions: `A = ones(2); A(:,:,2) = ones(2);` will, for example, give you a 3-dimensional array of size 2-by-2-by-2, with ones all over.

What you want, is probably want something like this:

```
A = [] % No prealocation. Fix for speed-up.
files = dir('./Day*/sample_ids.txt');
for file = files
    temp = load(file.name);
    A(:,:,size(A,3)+1) = temp;
end

disp(A) % display the contents of A afterards...
```

I haven't tested this code extensively, but it should work OK.

**A few important points:**

1. All files must contain matrices of the *exact same dimensions* - MATLAB can't handle arrays that have different dimensions in different layers (at least not with regular arrays - you could use cell arrays, but that quickly becomes more complicated...). Think of it as trying to build  a matrix from vectors of different lengths.
2. If you have a lot of data, and you know how much, you can save a lot of time by pre-allocating A. This is as easy as `A = zeros(k,l,m)` for `m` datafiles with `k` rows and `l` columns in each. If you do this, you'll also have to figure out the index of the current file, so you can use that as the third index in the assignment (on the second line in the loop block). I leave this as an internet research excersize :)